# How to replace values in an attribute table for one column?

Tags: python, gdal, shapefile, arcpy, ogr

I need to replace values in an attribute table for one column (replace zeroes in column named "label" to 100). Is this possible using ogr or python? I have to do this for 500+ shapefiles.

Comment: Yes you can easily do this in python. What did you try or where are you stuck ? You can start by having a look to the [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) python function (in order to traverse directory structure and get the name of your files) then you could give a try to the [`fiona`](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona) python module (it relies on OGR but offers an easier API, especially when you are only working with attributes). Depending on whether in a hurry you are to get the task done, you could also use the `threading` module in addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Esri ArcGIS realm, [Update Cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) are typically used for this type of operation.

For example

```
import arcpy

# Your input feature class
fc = r'C:\path\to\your.gdb\feature_class'

# Start an update cursor and change values from 0 to 100 in a field called "your_field"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "your_field") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == 0:
            row[0] = 100
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```